# Repeated Bernoulli Trials, Wins-Losses

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Consider 
    $$X(t)=\mbox{Number of wins} - \mbox{Number of losses}$$
for $t$ Bernoulli($\theta$) trials.

I calculated that 
    $$P(X(t) = x) = {t \choose (t-x)/2} \theta^{\frac{t+x}{2}} (1- \theta)^{\frac{t-x}{2}}$$
i.e. (winning trials - losing trials) = $x$ and (winning trials + losing trials) = $t$.

If we let $S = \{X(t)\}_{t=0}^{T}$, my question then is:

For an arbitrary integer $x$, what is $P(x \in S)$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Knowing the probability for one $t$, you will still be led to an infinite expansion of inclusion-exclusion when you take the union over all values of $t$, so there's a chance that there is no closed-form for this.  Would you settle for an asymptotic formula in terms of $x$, e.g. perhaps a formula predicting the value $P(x \in S)$ with a small error bound in terms of $x$ compared to the predicted value?

Comment: I'd settle for anything, its simply a question that popped into my head. I can see that for $\theta>0.5$ then for $x>0$, $P(x \in S) \rightarrow 1$ so I think the interesting part is considering the $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is performing a random walk with drift $2\theta-1$ and $S_T$ is the range of $X$ up to time $T$, if $\theta=\frac12$ then $P(x\in S_T)\to1$ for every $x$, when $T\to\infty$. If $\theta\gt\frac12$ then $P(x\in S_T)\to1$ for every $x\geqslant0$, when $T\to\infty$. If $\theta\lt\frac12$ then $P(x\in S_T)\to1$ for every $x\leqslant0$, when $T\to\infty$.

By symmetry, the only remaining case is when $x\gt0$ and $\theta\lt\frac12$. Then $P(x\in S_T)\to h^x$ where $h=\lim\limits_{T\to\infty}P(1\in S_T)$. The usual one-step Markov recursion indicates that $h=(1-\theta)\cdot1+\theta\cdot h^2$ hence $h=\theta/(1-\theta)$.

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that $X(t+1)$ is obtained by applying one more trial after $X(t)$.  I didn't read the question this way, I took $X(t)$ and $X(t')$ to be independent when $t \neq t'$.  Is your answer still valid in that case?

Comment: This is the answer to the question as I meant it, thank you. If $X(t)$ and $X(t')$ are independent do you think $P(x \in S) \rightarrow 1$ for all $x$. Thats what my intuition says??